# OgnlContext Get information about the node that call StrutsTypeConverter

Tags: html, struts, ognl

I'am adding a s:textfield that format the value from a Date

```
<s:textfield labelposition="left" name="ttt" key="xxx" type="date" />
<s:textfield labelposition="left" name="ttt" key="xxx" type="datetime" />
```

The platform call a customized StrutsTypeConverter I've written but I must write the date in two different formats on "type" basis

date = "yyyy-MM-dd";
datetime = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm";

How can i get the information about the type of the tag I'm using from the

public String convertToString(Map context, Object o)  signature?

Comment: You can't; all you get is the request parameters.

Comment: Not possible, agree.

Comment: Use different types in action class. Or create different converters and map them by action property name not type.